# Left-align cvskills in awesome cv

Tags: latex

I am using the latex template:
https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv

I wanted to left-align the cvskills section. I have tried riggedright, \begin{flushleft}, but it's still not working.

Below is how I used cvskills:

```
\cvsection{Skills}
\cvskill
{Programming} % Category
{Java, Python, C/C++, Go, OCaml} % Skills
\cvskill
{Web Programming}
{HTML, CSS, JQuery, Javascript, TypeScript}
```

It was displayed as the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same and used this:

```
\cvsection{Skills}
\begin{cvskills}
    \vspace{2mm}
\cvskill
    {Programming}
    {Java, Python, C/C++, OCaml}
    \vspace{2mm}
\cvskill
    {Web Prgramming}
    {HTML, CSS, JQuery, Javascript, Typescript}
\end{cvskills}
```

I added a space {2mm} after each entry, remove it if you prefer. I get this:

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lleLQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

**None** of the previous answers help you left-align the skill titles. As already mentioned [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457952/left-indent-names-of-skills-in-awesome-cv-latex), you'll have two options to left-align the skill titles:

**Solution 1.** Modify the `awesome-cv.cls` template by searching this chunk of code (~line 629)

```
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
\vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
\vspace{-2.0mm}
\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{\textwidth * \real{0.9}}}
```

and change the `r` (right-aligned) in the last line to an `l` (left-aligned)

**Solution 2.** Without resorting a template change, use `\hfill` instead. As in

```
\cvskill
   {Programming \hfill} % Category
   {Java, Python, C/C++, Go, OCaml} % Skills
```

Answer (score -1):

I used a new section Skills with the updated version. Here is my example, it should work!!

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cvsection{Competências}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTENT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{cvskills}

%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cvskill
    {Softwares} % Category
    {Office, MATLAB, SolidWorks, Creo Parametric, Inventor, ANSYS, CorelDraw} % Skills

%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cvskill
    {Idiomas} % Category
    {Português (nativo), Inglês (fluente), Alemão (básico)} % Skills

%---------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cvskills}
```